# python: class override "is" behavior

Tags: python

I'm writing a class which encapsulates any arbitrary object, including simple types. I want the "is" keyword to operate on the encapsulated value, such as this behavior:

```
Wrapper(True) is True -> True
Wrapper(False) is True -> False
Wrapper(None) is None -> True
Wrapper(1) is 1 -> True
```

Is there any object method I can override to get this behavior?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

No. `is`, `and`, and `or` cannot be overloaded.

Comment: Is that in Python documentation anywhere? Can't find anything verifying this.

Comment: The only reference is their absence in §3.4 of the langref. http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names

Comment: This answer is quite old. Is this still true for latest Python versions?

Comment: @Fran: Yes. The behavior regarding these operators has not changed.

Comment: I think I know why `is` cannot be overriden. Dictionary look ups and set lookups use `is` for fast equality checking since `__eq__` is overridable and potentially really slow. If `is` behavior was overridable there would be no way to guarantee fast dictionary lookup which would be detrimental to python's performance.

Comment: python3 here: seems like `and` and `or` can be overloaded, with `__and__`, `__rand__`, `__or__`, `__ror__`. Type `dir(int)` in the console to convince yourself.
**EDIT:** my bad, they overload `&` and `|`, not `and` and `or`

Comment: @Alejandro how can `dict` and `set` lookup use `is`? if the key is, say a `str`, then each instance of the same string should match. in `dict` and `set` lookup, speed is achieved by hashing, after which a `__eq__` test is done

Comment: @user3204459 Good point. No way could `is` be used in dictionary lookups. I don't know why these can't be overloaded...

Answer (score 7):

`is` itself cannot be overloaded, but you may be interested in other ["Reflection" magic methods](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/#reflection) which may be suitable for your use case (since you are looking at this thread):

> `__instancecheck__(self, instance)` 
>   Checks if an instance is an instance of the class you defined (e.g. `isinstance(instance, class)`.
>
> `__subclasscheck__(self, subclass)` 
>   Checks if a class subclasses the class you defined (e.g. `issubclass(subclass, class)`).

Answer (score 4):

Generally, if you want to test equality in terms of value (if x is 1, or True, or None), you'd use the `==` operator anyway. If you want to use the `is` operator, you're generally testing if something is referring to something else, like `list1 is list2`.

If you want to define special behavior for `==`, you can define `__eq__` in your class definition.

Comment: `x is 1` is dangerous, but `x is None` is perfectly fine. `True`, `False`, and `None` are [guaranteed to be singletons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27276610/boolean-identity-true-vs-is-true), and I *think* integers -5 through 257 are also statically allocated in CPython, but you might be able to create one of those integers that isn't `is` identical.

Answer (score 0):

`is` can't be overloaded, because its semantic is independent of the type of the compared objects (unlike other operators such as `==`).

The semantic of `is` is to check if two "keywords" refer to the same object. Namely, `a is b` is equivalent to `id(a) == id(b)` (the function `id()` returning the memory address of an object).

What you can do however, is to override the `__new__` method to return an existing object rather than creating a new one:

```py
class Wrapper:

    _cache = {}

    def __new__(cls, value):
        if value not in cls._cache:
            cls._cache[value] = super().__new__(cls)
        return cls._cache[value]

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value


print(Wrapper(True) is Wrapper(True))  # True
print(Wrapper(False) is Wrapper(True))  # False
print(Wrapper(None) is Wrapper(None))  # True
print(Wrapper(1) is Wrapper(1))  # True
```

This is quite silly, but may be useful in some use cases. However, keep in mind that `__init__()` will still be executed after `__new__()` even if the latter returns an existing instance.

Answer (score -3):

> No. `is`, `and`, and `or` cannot be overloaded.

Indeed. I believe that keywords are reserved and cannot be overloaded or changed.

See:
http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords

"The following identifiers are used as reserved words, or keywords of the language, and cannot be used as ordinary identifiers."

The list is:
['and', 'as', 'assert', 'break', 'class', 'continue', 'def', 'del', 'elif', 'else', 'except', 'exec', 'finally', 'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import', 'in', 'is', 'lambda', 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'print', 'raise', 'return', 'try', 'while', 'with', 'yield']

This list can be viewed through the command

keyword.kwlist

(Don't forget to import keyword first)

Also:

keyword.iskeyword('is')

Returns True

---

Update:

My answer was bad and I should feel bad.

I've messed with del myself. I don't know why I didn't notice that...

2nd try:

The following documentation provides a full list of customizable behavior on classes. This includes all the methods for overriding and overloading operators. 'is' is not included.

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names

Best I can do.

Comment: But `del` can be overloaded, e.g., you can overload `del x[i]` or `del x.attr`.  The question is about whether the semantics can be altered, not the syntax.

Comment: `in` can be directly overloaded. `as` can be partially overloaded, in a context manager. `import` and `for` can be indirectly overloaded.