# How to override the `is` operator

Tags: python, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python: class override “is” behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993239/python-class-override-is-behavior)

I am trying to override the `is` operator, so that I could do something like

```
if tom is writer:
   print 'tom is writing'
elif tom is programmer:
   print 'tom is programming'
```

Is this possible in python?

Comment: Do you mean "is", or "isa"?  This looks like "isa" to me.

Comment: Assuming "tom" in your example is an object, you can't just get away with methods like tom.is_writer() and tom.is_programmer()?

Comment: @uzi In my case, `writer` and `programmer` are jobs and there are too many of them to be implemented in the class of tom. Currently I am using something like `tom.works_as_a(writer)`.

Comment: Recommend you just replace works_as_a() with is_a(). Don't override things that are that fundamental to the language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't override 'is' because it tests whether two objects are *the same object* by comparing their memory addresses (i.e. pointer comparison). You probably want to override '==' by implementing tom's `__eq__` method.

Answer (score 3):

The Python way to test for the type of an object is to use isinstance, as in `isinstance(tom,Writer)`.

But whenever you start to write code that reads like your example, think about using polymorphism instead.  Here is a simple class hierarchy that does what you want, without a single call to isinstance:

```
class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def is_doing(self):
        return "working"

class Writer(Worker):
    def is_doing(self):
        return "writing"

class Programmer(Worker):
    def is_doing(self):
        return "programming"

workers = [
    Writer("Tom"),
    Programmer("Dick"),
    ]

for w in workers:
    print "%s is %s" % (w.name, w.is_doing())
```

Prints:

```
Tom is writing
Dick is programming
```

Now you can just add new subclasses to Worker and implement is_doing, and you don't have to maintain some table of type-to-activity values.

This pattern of polymorphism is traditional O-O, but in Python, you aren't even restricted to subclasses of Worker - any object that implements `is_doing` and has a `name` attribute will work:

```
class Fish(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.name = n
    def is_doing(self):
        return "swimming"

workers.append(Fish("Wanda"))

for w in workers:
    print "%s is %s" % (w.name, w.is_doing())
```

will print:

```
Tom is writing
Dick is programming
Wanda is swimming
```

Comment: Thx. But polymorphism won't work for me, because the entities that I called `job` is not exactly jobs. And a person can have multiple entities of such kind at the same time.