# A surprise (perhaps a minunderstanding) in python about `if a:` and `if a is not None:`

Tags: python-2.7, conditional-operator

I used to think that following two statements are equal in python2.7

```
if a: print "not none"
```

And

```
if a is not None: print "not none"
```

Today, while working, something peculiar happened. This is reproduced below

```
In [7]: random_stim
Out[7]: <Element '{http://morphml.org/networkml/schema}random_stim' at 0x1acf810>
In [9]: if random_stim: print "Not None"

In [10]: if not random_stim: print "Not None"
Not None

In [12]: if random_stim is not None: print "Not none"
Not none
```

Is something strange happening here? Or I missed something about python if statement?

PS: random_stim is [lxml Element](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if a` checks if `a`1 is truthy. More specifically, it checks the return value of `a.__bool__()`. With `int`s, this effectively looks like this:

```
# explaining is easier with python's syntax
if myInt == 0:
  myInt.__bool__() returns False
else:
  myInt.__bool__() returns True
```

Note that in the above example, I was not providing actual python code. As @jwodder points out, the post should say `myInt.__nonzero__` in python2 (I hope the point is not lost on you despite the lack of specific correctness, though).

It is also the case that `NoneType.__bool__()` always returns False.

Now, onto the second half of your question:

The `is` operator checks if the memory locations of the two operands are the same, despite whether they are to be considered identical. The best analogy I can think of for this right now, is identical twins. Consider that you have two friends, who are identical twins. While it may be easy to confuse one for the other, while looking at them individually, if you track their GPS coordinates, you'll likely to never make that mistake.
Along those lines, the `is` operator checks for the specific location in memory (RAM) where the operands are held and returns `True` only if both operands point to the same memory location (in much the same way as you'd confuse the two twins only if they were standing on the exact same  coordinates).

Now, in many cases, `if a is b` and `if a==b` work the same. This happens with immutable types like `int`s and `str`s (this isn't entirely true depending on how you build your `str`s; for example, `'abc'=='ab'+'c'` is True, but `'abc' is 'ab'+'c'` is not) and -- drumroll please -- `NoneType`s.

Comment: `__bool__` is Python 3, and the question is tagged `python-2.7`, where `__nonzero__` is used instead.

Answer (score 3):

`if` tests whether the provided expression has a `True` ["truth value"](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), which isn't the same thing as being non-`None`.  An `if` test will be `False` if the given expression is `None` *or* 0 (any numeric type) *or* an empty string/list/dictionary/tuple/set/other container *or* an object whose `__nonzero__` or `__len__` method returns `False` or 0.

Comment: The document says that `None` is considered `False`.

Comment: @Dilawar: Right, *among other values*, which is how `if x: print "foo"` can print nothing even when `x` isn't `None`.

Comment: Oh, you mean that `None` is False but non-None is not always `True`?

Answer (score 1):

The `is` test checks object identity.  In Python there is only one `None` value.  Consider this code:

```
x = None
print(x is None)  # prints True
print(x == None)  # prints True
print(not x)  # prints True

class A(object):
    pass

a = A()
b = A()
print(a is a)  # prints True
print(a is b)  # prints False
```

Python provides a built-in function `id()` that prints some sort of unique identifier for a value.  I think in practice it just prints the address of the object.  A way to remember what `is` does is to imagine that

```
x is y
```

evaluates as:

```
id(x) == id(y)
```

One important point about the `is` operator: you can't overload it.  The `is` operator is a built-in with no override.  You can, in principle, overload the `==` operator to do tricky things.  (But `id()` returns a plain old `int`, so the expression `id(x) == id(y)` is comparing two plain old `int` values, and the `==` in that case can't do anything tricky.)

Consider this example of code you should never write:

```
class Liar(object):
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return 0

x = Liar()
print(x == None)  # prints True (which is a lie!)
print(x is None)  # prints False
```

You can overload `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, and `not` as well as `==` but you can never overload the `is` operator.  I think that is a very good thing; it provides a trusted foundation upon which you can depend.

If you write `x is None` that expression will only be true if `x is None`.

[python: class override "is" behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993239/python-class-override-is-behavior)