# Is it possible to overload logical and in Python?

Tags: python, operator-overloading, logical-operators

I was under the impression it was possible to overload `and` in Python, but reading through the docs just now, I realized that `__and__` refers to the bitwise `&` operator, not logical `and`.

Am I overlooking something, or is it not possible to overload logical `and` in Python?

Comment: I'm curious: what would you like to make an overloaded `and` do? Or are you just asking for purely theoretical reasons?

Comment: Purely theoretical. I'm writing something that needs to work with Python AST. For most things like `Add`, I replace it with a call to `__add__`, but I was surprised that I couldn't find a function to replace an `And` node in AST with.

Comment: I don’t see a good reason why you would want to introduce custom behavior for logical operators that does not match the behavior from evaluating `__bool__`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No this is not possible. There is a [proposal](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0335/) that adds this functionality but for now, it is rejected.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993239/python-class-override-is-behavior).

Comment: Hm. `is` makes some sense to me, but I'm surprised that `and` and `or` cannot be overloaded.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed a limitation of the language. But you *can* override the bitwise operators & and | , as you noticed. This is used by e.g. SQLAlchemy and you can also use it yourself of course.

Answer (score 2):

There is no straight way to do this. You could override `__nonzero__` for your objects to modify their truth value.

```
class Truth:

    def __init__(self, truth):
        self.truth = truth

    def __nonzero__(self):
        return self.truth

t = Truth(True)
f = Truth(False)

print bool(t and t)
print bool(t and f)
print bool(f and f)
```

Comment: Compatibility tip: `__nonzero__` has been renamed to [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=nonzero#object.__bool__) in 3.X.