# Using numpy.where() to compare numbers in an array to an interval

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean-expression

I have an array of numbers:

`my_arr = np.array([n, n+1, n+2 ... , m-1, m]`

I want to create an array of Booleans which indicate which numbers are in some (closed) interval, `[A,B]`, to operate on some other related array that has the same shape. There are two cases:

#### Case 1: `B >= m` or `A <= n`

This case is trivial; the interval can be fully described with only one Boolean expression, and `np.where()` provides the solution to testing my array; e.g.:

`my_boolean_arr = np.where(my_arr >= A)`

or it's equivalent for B. **This works.**

#### Case 2: `n <= A` and `m >= B`

Here, I run into problems. I can no longer reduce my interval expression into a "single" Boolean expression. Python allows me to come *close*: the expression `A < x < B` will return a single (correct) Boolean. However,

`my_boolean_arr = np.where(A <= my_arr <= B)`

now fails:

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

So, Two questions. First, how do I make this work? Second, why does this fail?

Comment: Why does `np.where(arr >= A and arr <= B)`, which was the first thing I tried, fail?

Comment: Python doesn't allow overloading `and` and `or`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32311518. See the warnings in the numpy docs: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#comparison-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operators "and" and "or" are not defined for numpy arrays.
In your case, you can use np.logical_and instead:

```
my_boolean_arr = np.logical_and(my_arr>=A, my_arr<=B)
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html

Alternative way is to use operator &

```
my_boolean_arr = (my_arr>=A) & (my_arr<=B)
```