# is there a magic method for logical and and or in python?

Tags: python

I thought they are `__and__` and `__or__` but turns out they are for bitwise comparisons not logical ones. Are there such methods for the logical comparators?

Comment: I don't think this has changed since the much [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311518/is-it-possible-to-overload-logical-and-in-python) and the rejected [PEP 335](https://peps.python.org/pep-0335/)

Comment: Kinda surprising that `and` / `or`  / `not` - all 3 aren't implemented using dunder method, wonder if the reason for not implementing logical op that way is part of *"Althought practicality beats purity"*

Comment: It depends what you want to do. Implementing `__bool__` for your class may be the way to go.

Comment: they are implemented as part of the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__not__) module. In the link there is this consideration _Note that there is no __not__() method for object instances; only the interpreter core defines this operation._