# Override 'is' operator for mocked object

Tags: python, mocking, overriding, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

Simplified code: I have a function that expects either a number or None, and returns `True` if it's `None`, and `False` if it's a number, like:

```
def function(var):
    return var is None
```

I want to pass a mocked object and test it with the `is` operator like this:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock

mock = Mock(return_value=None)
assert function()
```

This will fail although I mocked the value to be `None`. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mocking-magic-methods), there are many supported magic methods, but none let me implement the behavior for this case.

Changing to `assert mock == None` would let me use the `__eq__` operator, but I don't want to touch the code (and apparently using `is` is faster than `==` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3257957/5987307))

Comment: You cannot change `is`

Comment: How could you say `is` would is be faster if you were trying to implement both?

Comment: "Changing to assert mock == None would let me use the __eq__ operator, but I would like to avoid it since apparently using is is faster than == according to this answer." This is not going to be a significant performance issue

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: might not be a performance issue, but there's difference in performance
>>> timeit.Timer("None == None").timeit()
0.026401887999782048
>>> timeit.Timer("None is None").timeit()
0.02391680099935911
BTW, these are the average values

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga can you be more specific why I can't override `is`? I'm not convinced.

Comment: @ezib because the language provides no hook for `is`, which **always** means identity.

Comment: Honestly, what you are describing doesn't make a lot of sense. What are you trying to test such that your mock object must be *identical* (or even equal to) `None`?

Comment: @ezib See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html. `is` compares `id`, which must be unique, and in CPython is the memory address. (Also, this is probably the underlying reason it is faster -- there's no hook to modify it)

Comment: If you _could_ override the behaviour of `is`, you would lose the speed benefit anyway.

Comment: @dwhswenson thanks! That explains a bit why the operator isn't "overridable".

Comment: @khelwood the operator would be overriden only for the mocked object in a test case, not used on runtime

Comment: In general, you probably want to mock a function (and results of that function), not the result object. This works: `import mock; m = mock.Mock(return_value=None); assert m() is None`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I want to mock, in a test, a variable that can be either None or a number. In the main code, None has a different treatment than for a number

Comment: I updated the description a bit

Comment: @ezib I mean if `is` was subject to overriding, it would be slower, even if you were not overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using `isinstance()` instead of `is` would work for you.  Declaring your mock object class as `class MockInt(int):` will make isinstance() recognizes the variables as int:

```
class MockInt(int):
      def __init__(self,value): self.value = value

i = MockInt(23)

print( isinstance(i,int) ) # True
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

don't forget the parentheses when there is a `return_value`

```
from unittest.mock import Mock

mock = Mock(return_value=None)
assert function(mock())
```

### More info

If you want to pass a variable that holds `None` to test `function` there is no need to use `Mock`. you can write the below code:

```
mock = None
assert function(mock)
```

`Mock`'s best usage is when you want to mock either a method or an object with a more complex structure. so, when you write `mock = Mock(return_value=None)` you must **call** `mock` to return the `return_value`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by many, `is` is "unoverridable" because it's a fast equality check of ids. That's why there's a performance difference in comparison to `__eq__`.

More about that in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) and in the comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3993244/5987307).